# How can I merge historical source/campaign/medium in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, utm-parameters

I typically direct traffic to the sites I work on with heavy use of UTMs for later analysis, eg:

```
domain.com/some_page?utm_source=eblast&utm_campaign=january_campaign...etc
```

Unfortunately the one I'm working on now has a whole list of different spelling variations - Email, eBlast, Eblast etc. How can I merge these in Google Analytics? They should all be the same entry

[image: how to merge these]

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change these once they are in Analytics. Same thing with filters, once the data is in GA, it is there.

Send this report to the person writing those emails and have them pick one. Or to your boss and explain what is going on. Compared to five different tags it might be better if they didn't use the tag at all.